# App is closing - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: java, android, onclick, illegalstateexception, java.lang.class

FATAL EXCEPTION:

Main
Process: com.example.joquempo, PID: 4111
java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Could not execute method for android:onClick

I don't know what is the problem here, images are well-linked. I am basically trying to create a jokempo game, supposed to be quite easy but now I am receiving the error above which stuck me on this.

```
package com.example.joquempo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void selecionadoPedra(View view) {
        this.opcaoSelecionada("pedra");
    }

    public void selecionadoPapel(View view) {
        this.opcaoSelecionada("papel");
    }

    public void selecionadoTesoura(View view) {

        this.opcaoSelecionada("tesoura");
    }

    public void opcaoSelecionada(String opcaoSelecionada) {
        ImageView imageResultado = findViewById(R.id.imageResultado);
        TextView textResultado = findViewById(R.id.textResultado);

        int numero = new Random().nextInt(3);
        String[] opcoes = {"pedra", "papel", "tesoura"};
        String opcaoApp = opcoes[numero];

        switch (opcaoApp) {
            case "pedra":
                imageResultado.setImageResource(R.drawable.pedra);
                break;

            case "papel":
                imageResultado.setImageResource(R.drawable.papel);
                break;

            case "tesoura":
                imageResultado.setImageResource(R.drawable.tesoura);
                break;
        }
        if ((opcaoApp.equals("tesoura") && opcaoSelecionada.equals("papel")) ||
                (opcaoApp.equals("papel") && opcaoSelecionada.equals("pedra")) ||
                (opcaoApp.equals("pedra") && opcaoSelecionada.equals("tesoura"))) {
            textResultado.setText("Você Perdeu :( ");
        } else if ((opcaoSelecionada.equals("tesoura") && opcaoApp.equals("papel")) ||
                (opcaoSelecionada.equals("papel") && opcaoApp.equals("pedra")) ||


                (opcaoSelecionada.equals("pedra") && opcaoApp.equals("tesoura"))) {
            textResultado.setText("Você ganhou! :D ");
        } else {
            textResultado.setText("Empatamos ;) ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the LogCat output, especially the line that starts "Caused by..."